# How to respond to Mahlzeit?

Tags: phrase

When I'm getting lunch at the cafeteria in Germany, the lunch ladies always say "Mahlzeit!". Do I respond by saying "Danke" or "Mahlzeit"?

Also, does "Mahlzeit" mean something like "Guten Appetit"?

Comment: In our company, "Mahlzeit" is always responded with "Mahlzeit". Mahlzeit is said in a time span around the lunch, while "Guten Appetit" is said when you see that the person eats.

Comment: Ich finde die in manchen Gegenden und Firmensubkulturen verbreitete 'Mahlzeiterei' widerlich. Ich gehe zur Arbeit, um zu arbeiten, und ich möchte nicht von allerlei Kollegen ab 11 Uhr vormittags dauernd ans Essen erinnert werden. Oder wenn schon, dann ohne die maulfaul-achtlose Verkürzung, denn eigentlich sollte es ***Gesegnete Mahlzeit!*** heißen. Ich antworte darum mit ***Danke, gleichfalls***. Dies ist aber eine Form der Rebellion. Üblich ist es in der Tat, mit Wiederholung des gleichen Worts zu antworten.